# Seam Page Action Not Being Called

Tags: java, jsf, seam, action

I've got a page that displays an entity, but before rendering the page I need to perform a lookup of the entity based on a parameter that is passed in.  To do this, I'm trying to use a Seam Page Action declared in my pages.xml file to call the lookup action before rendering the page.  My setup looks like this:

pages.xml:

```
<page view-id="/mypage.xhtml" action="#{mylookup.lookupEntity}"></page>
```

My action class:

```
@Name("myLookup")
@AutoCreate
public class MyLookup {

@RequestParameter
private String myParam;

...

public void lookupEntity() { ...}

...
}
```

Everything looks fine to me, but when I click on a link to take me to that page, my lookupEntity() action never gets called.  I've added breakpoints and logging statements, and it's clear that it never gets called.

What is a typical cause for this?  Is there someplace I should be looking for more info on why this failed?

Answer (score 2):

**Simply** because the called component name (#{mylookup.lookupEntity}) **does not match** component name (#{myLookup.lookupEntity}).

Comment: That was just an example to show how I configured the action and pages.xml.  It wasn't copy/paste code  :)

Comment: @Shadowman Thanks for reply. Have you tried SeamTest ??? Where does mypage.xhtml file is placed ??? Which Seam version ??? Some additional info ???

Answer (score 0):

I also suspected it does not work, till I replace log.trace with log.info and saw that it does. Maybe some of you are falling on the same trap I went through.